# How to use the Reserved Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I taken the small instance from amazon EC2. I unsed the linux/unix option while purchasing the instance. Now in reserved tab that show me instance is running. I am confused how to use that reserved instance.

Answer (score 4):

The reserved instance is used by the first instance (of the same size) that is running.  So if you stop your small instance, you'll find the reserved instance is stopped too.

By buying a reserved instance you simply get a discount on the running costs of a single instance (of the appropriate size).

Comment: Do I Need to create the instance using any os like Centos. Are you saying this.

Comment: You create the instance in the same way you create any other - it's just the billing is different if you've paid for reserved instance upfront.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you boot your instance to the same zone that you purchased the reserved instance in.  If you payed for one in us-east-1d and you boot the instance in us-east-1c you won't get your discounted rate.